# Highchart tooltip & events from external function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to add external function for highchart tooltip formatter and events something like code given below.
How to add it externally.

```
 $(function(){
      var highchartObj = chart: {renderTo: 'rightBottomContainer'},xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']}, series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]} 
      rchart = new Highcharts.Chart(highchartObj);
        rchart.Point.prototype.tooltipFormatter = function (useHeader) {
        //var point = this, series = point.series;
        return "AAAAAA";
    };

});
```

Comment: How do you mean externally? Your code seems good enough to put in an external file if that's what you mean.

Comment: Externally means I don't want to put tooltip code inside the highchart object. 
Externally means after rendering the chart How can I assign tooltip function to the chart something like 
`<pre><code>
 rchart.Point.prototype.tooltipFormatter = function (useHeader) {
        //var point = this, series = point.series;
        return "AAAAAA";
    }; 
</code></pre>`
 But that is not working.

Comment: @primavera133 - any solutions for this ??

Comment: No sorry, but I'm not that familiar with highcharts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your function somewhere like

```
function tooltipFormatter(){
    //your format here
}
```

Then pass this function to Highcharts configuration object inside `tooltip` object as `formatter`:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(..., tooltip: { formatter: tooltipFormatter }, ...);
```

As a result you can have your code in a separate function that will be passed inside Highcharts object.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NCnS5/

Docs for `formatter` parameter: http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip--formatter